# how i got the error response in Dio Package

Tags: flutter, dart

hi all i use Dio Package and i got error  response but i need to print the value from error  response not print just error
i got like this :

```
flutter: error:DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]
flutter: #0      DioMixin.assureDioError
flutter: #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
flutter: #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
```

but i want the error response print the value like this :

```
{
status: "error",
code: "rateLimited",
message: "bla bla bla bla bla."
}
```

and this is my code

```
Future<void> getTechnology() async {
    await DioHelper.getData(
      path: 'v2/top-headlines',
      query: {
        'country': 'ae',
        'category': 'technology',
        'apiKey': '1111',
      },
    ).then(
      (value) async {
        _technology = value.data['articles'];
      },
    ).catchError(
      (onError) => print(
        throw onError.toString(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
Future<void> getTechnology() async {
    await DioHelper.getData(
      path: 'v2/top-headlines',
      query: {
        'country': 'ae',
        'category': 'technology',
        'apiKey': '1111',
      },
    ).then(
      (value) async {
        _technology = value.data['articles'];
      },
    ).catchError(
      (err) {
        if (err is DioError) {
          print(err.response);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```